# Automatically proxy WebSockets endpoints with nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, websocket

I am trying to write a Nginx reverse proxy configuration for a web application (specifically JupyterLab, but this question is intended to be generic).

The web application uses multiple WebSockets endpoints in multiple disjoint URL hierarchies. For example,

- `/jupyter/api/yjs/...`
- `/jupyter/terminals/...`
- `/jupyter/api/collaboration/room/...`
- (and others)

Are all WebSockets endpoints. I wrote a tentative configuration that looks like this:

```
                location /jupyter/ {
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        client_max_body_size 0;
                        proxy_pass http://jupyter;
                }

                location ~ ^/jupyter/api/yjs/ {
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
                        proxy_pass http://jupyter;
                }

                <repeated sections for other WebSockets endpoints>
```

However, the full list of WebSockets endpoints is not documented. I tried to analyze nginx and application logs and infer which URLs need to be proxied as WebSockets, but this is obviously unreliable.

---

Is there any way to write a nginx configuration such that it would proxy all incoming WebSockets requests as WebSockets, and plain HTTP requests as plain HTTP, **without hard-coding the WebSockets locations in the nginx config**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is achievable using a map variable and some knowledge about WebSocket.

A WebSocket connection is initiated using a HTTP 1.1 request with two headers: `Connection: Upgrade` and `Upgrade: WebSocket`, both of which are hop-by-hop (and thus are not normally proxied).

We could simply enable HTTP 1.1 on the backend connection with `proxy_http_version 1.1` and proxy both headers using `proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection` and `proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade`. However, we'd still need to provide `Connection: close` on regular (non-WebSocket) requests to be consistent with NGINX defaults. Thus:

```
# in http context
map $http_upgrade $proxy_connection {
        ''      'close';
        default 'upgrade';
}

<...>

# in server context
location /jupyter/ {
        # WebSocket support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection $proxy_connection;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        client_max_body_size 0;

        proxy_pass http://jupyter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found managing reverse proxies easier using a web-ui application `nginx-proxy-manager`. And I found an option when creating proxy hosts to enable `websockets support`. If you are interested in using nginxproxymanager. You might be able to easily proxy all incoming WebSockets requests as WebSockets using this application.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the hint. As it stands though, this doesn't answer the question — I specifically asked a question about _writing_ nginx configuration, i. e. a piece of text.